# Error when Adding mathtools package

Tags: packages

I am writing a report in latex and i need to use cuthesis library (found at http://www.nmai.ca/resources).  I don't know why when I add mathtools library, lots of errors are generated. Can you please help me fix this error?
One of the errors: Undefined control sequence\@calc@post@scan ...st@scan \else \def \calc@next{\calc@error #1}\fi \fi \f...\newtheorem{thy}{Theorem}[chapter]

Here is the code

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[phd,4committee,nonsequential]{cuthesis}
\usepackage{mathtools}  
\usepackage{amssymb, amsbsy, amsthm, eqnarray}             % Mathematical symbols by AMS-LaTeX
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}    % see http://ctan.org/pkg/xcolor
\usepackage{setspace,etoolbox,titlesec,sectsty}



%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Define some colors
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\definecolor{cadmiumred}{rgb}{0.89, 0.0, 0.13}
\definecolor{darkBlue}{rgb}{0,0,.6}
\definecolor{darkRed}{rgb}{.7,0,0}

%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Set the counter
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{5}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}  % Displying the section/subsection number
\interfootnotelinepenalty=10000

%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Define Chapters and Section Headers font, Color and Shape
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\newcommand{\colbox}{\colorbox[rgb]{1,0.41,0.13}}
\sectionfont{\color{orange}}                 % sets colour of sections
\subsectionfont{\color{RoyalBlue}}           % sets colour of subsections
\subsubsectionfont{\color{ForestGreen}}      % sets colour of subsubsections
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\normalfont\huge\bfseries\color{darkBlue}}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{2pt}{\Huge} 
\titlespacing{\chapter}{0pt}{1pt}{1pt} 
\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{2pt}{4pt}
\titlespacing{\subsection}{0pt}{2pt}{4pt}
\makeatletter % changes the catcode/category code of @ to 11
\renewcommand{\@seccntformat}[1]{\csname the#1\endcsname)\;} % Add bracket after section # and small space by\;
\makeatother % changes the catcode/category code of @ back to 12

%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Define the some styles
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\newtheoremstyle{exstyle}                % name
  {3pt}                                          % Space above
  {3pt}                                          % Space below
  {}                                             % Body font
  {}                                             % Indent amount (empty = no indent, \parindent = para indent)
  {\normalfont\color{cadmiumred}}% Thm head font
  {:}                                            % Punctuation after thm head
  %{.5em}                                        % Space after thm head: " " = normal interword space;
  {\newline}                                     %\newline = linebreak
  {\thmname{#1}\thmnumber{ #2}\thmnote{ (#3)}} %Thm head spec (can be left empty, meaning 'normal')

\theoremstyle{exstyle}
%\newtheorem{mydef}{Definition}[chapter]
%\newtheorem{ex}{Example}[chapter]

\newtheoremstyle{mytheoremstyle}  % name
        {\topsep}                     % Space above
        {\topsep}                     % Space below
        {\slshape\selectfont}         % Body font
        {}                            % Indent amount
        {\bfseries\color{cadmiumred}} % Theorem head font {\bfseries\itshape\
        {:}                           % Punctuation after theorem head
        %{.5em}                       % Space after theorem head
        {\newline}                                    %\newline = linebreak
        {\thmname{#1}\thmnumber{ #2}\thmnote{ (#3)}} % Theorem head spec (can be left empty, meaning 'normal')

\theoremstyle{mytheoremstyle}
\newtheorem{thy}{Theorem}[chapter]   
\newtheorem{coly}{Corollary}[chapter] 
\newtheorem{lem}{Lemma}[chapter] 
\newtheorem{pro}{Proposition}[chapter] 
\newtheorem{Res}{Result}[chapter] 
\newtheorem{prop}{Property}[chapter] 
\newtheorem{remark}{Remark}[chapter] 
\newtheorem{note}{Note}[chapter]

\numberwithin{equation}{chapter}


\DeclarePairedDelimiterX{\innp}[2]{\langle}{\rangle}{#1, #2}              %\innp[\bigg]{x}{y}
\DeclarePairedDelimiterX\norm[1]\lVert\rVert{\ifblank{#1}{\:\cdot\:}{#1}} %\norm[\bigg]{x}

\begin{document}

\chapter{First Chapter}\label{ch1:1}
\section{First Section}\label{ch1:sec1}

This is the first section

\section{Second Section}\label{ch1:sec2}

This is the second section

\subsection{Sub Section}\label{ch1:ssec2}

\begin{itemize}
   \item $\innp{S-\mathbf{d}}{\mathbf{d}}_\mathbf{w} = 0$ i.e. $S-\mathbf{d}$ is orthogonal to $\mathbf{d}$, so we obtain 
            \[
                    S^T\mathbf{d}=(S^T+\mathbf{d}^T-\mathbf{d}^T) \mathbf{d}= \norm[\big]{\mathbf{d}}^2
            \]
\end{itemize}



\end{document}
```

When I comment out the code below, these errors disappear and i have no idea why this is.

```
\newtheorem{thy}{Theorem}[chapter]   
\newtheorem{coly}{Corollary}[chapter] 
\newtheorem{lem}{Lemma}[chapter] 
\newtheorem{pro}{Proposition}[chapter] 
\newtheorem{Res}{Result}[chapter] 
\newtheorem{prop}{Property}[chapter] 
\newtheorem{remark}{Remark}[chapter] 
\newtheorem{note}{Note}[chapter]

\numberwithin{equation}{chapter}
```

Your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Which error did you get, exactly? I don't have the `cuthesis` package, but without that I don't get any errors on Overleaf.

Comment: Please provide the error message as @TorbjørnT. suggested. I downloaded `cuthesis` from http://www.nmai.ca/resources and minimized your example (only the packages `cuthesis`, `etoolbox` (for `\ifblank`) and `mathtools`, and the equation from your code) and that works without errors.

Comment: @Marijin, I use TeXnicCenter to code in LaTeX and I got 35 errors one of them is ! Undefined Control sequence. \@calc@post@scan...st@scan \else \def \calc@next{\calc@error #1} \fi \fi \fi... 1.106 \newtheorem{mydef}{Definition}[chapter]

Comment: @OlelDias please try to minimize the code yourself, by removing packages and document content until the error disappears. This will provide some clues on what causes the error.

Comment: @Marijn, I have minimized the code and removed some packages and nothing change. But when I comment out \numberwithin{equation}{chapter} and all \newtheorem{thy}{Theorem}[chapter]   I didn't get any error. So I think the problem is with the counting method and theorem environment?

Comment: @OlelDias the example as posted is _nothing like_ minimal. Think of people having to trace this to debug the issue, firstly you should give a link to the copy of cuthesis.cls you used, as it is not in the standard distributions and then you should remove every package not involved in the error. Do you really need to load massive packages such as tikz and tabu (which you don't appear to use) to show the error?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, I have updated the code.  I do require the use of all the libraries throughout the report.  I provided the link to the cuthesis.  I don't know why when I comment these \newtheorem and \numberwithin, these errors disappear but I am not able to create a theory environment with them.  Please note, that I tried to minimize the code as much as possible.  If i were to minimize further, the error will not generate.

Comment: @Marijn can you help please?

Comment: @OlelDias there are some strange things happening in the interaction between `cuthesis` and `amsthm`. I'll try to look at it later today.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you remove bits of `cuthesis.cls` until the error goes away you find this is a more minimal example:

```
\documentclass{report}
\makeatletter



\newcounter{mychapcitecount}




\def\cl@chapter{%
  \setcounter{mychapcitecount}{0}%
  \@ifundefined{@nonsequential}{%
    \@elt{section}\@elt{footnote}%
  }{%
    \@elt{equation}\@elt{figure}\@elt{footnote}\@elt{section}\@elt{table}%
  }}


\makeatother



\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{amsthm}             % Mathematical symbols by AMS-LaTeX

\usepackage{setspace,etoolbox,titlesec,sectsty}



%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Define some colors
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Set the counter
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


\newtheorem{thy}{Theorem}[chapter]   


\begin{document}



\end{document}
```

So you can undo that package's definition of `\cl@chapter` and find this version of your example runs without error

```
\documentclass{report}
\makeatletter
\let\foo\cl@chapter
\usepackage[phd,4committee,nonsequential]{cuthesis}
\let\cl@chapter\foo
\makeatother

\usepackage{mathtools}  
\usepackage{amssymb, amsbsy, amsthm, eqnarray}             % Mathematical symbols by AMS-LaTeX
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}    % see http://ctan.org/pkg/xcolor
\usepackage{setspace,etoolbox,titlesec,sectsty}



%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Define some colors
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\definecolor{cadmiumred}{rgb}{0.89, 0.0, 0.13}
\definecolor{darkBlue}{rgb}{0,0,.6}
\definecolor{darkRed}{rgb}{.7,0,0}

%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Set the counter
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{5}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}  % Displying the section/subsection number
\interfootnotelinepenalty=10000

%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Define Chapters and Section Headers font, Color and Shape
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\newcommand{\colbox}{\colorbox[rgb]{1,0.41,0.13}}
\sectionfont{\color{orange}}                 % sets colour of sections
\subsectionfont{\color{RoyalBlue}}           % sets colour of subsections
\subsubsectionfont{\color{ForestGreen}}      % sets colour of subsubsections
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\normalfont\huge\bfseries\color{darkBlue}}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{2pt}{\Huge} 
\titlespacing{\chapter}{0pt}{1pt}{1pt} 
\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{2pt}{4pt}
\titlespacing{\subsection}{0pt}{2pt}{4pt}
\makeatletter % changes the catcode/category code of @ to 11
\renewcommand{\@seccntformat}[1]{\csname the#1\endcsname)\;} % Add bracket after section # and small space by\;
\makeatother % changes the catcode/category code of @ back to 12

%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Define the some styles
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\newtheoremstyle{exstyle}                % name
  {3pt}                                          % Space above
  {3pt}                                          % Space below
  {}                                             % Body font
  {}                                             % Indent amount (empty = no indent, \parindent = para indent)
  {\normalfont\color{cadmiumred}}% Thm head font
  {:}                                            % Punctuation after thm head
  %{.5em}                                        % Space after thm head: " " = normal interword space;
  {\newline}                                     %\newline = linebreak
  {\thmname{#1}\thmnumber{ #2}\thmnote{ (#3)}} %Thm head spec (can be left empty, meaning 'normal')

\theoremstyle{exstyle}
%\newtheorem{mydef}{Definition}[chapter]
%\newtheorem{ex}{Example}[chapter]

\newtheoremstyle{mytheoremstyle}  % name
        {\topsep}                     % Space above
        {\topsep}                     % Space below
        {\slshape\selectfont}         % Body font
        {}                            % Indent amount
        {\bfseries\color{cadmiumred}} % Theorem head font {\bfseries\itshape\
        {:}                           % Punctuation after theorem head
        %{.5em}                       % Space after theorem head
        {\newline}                                    %\newline = linebreak
        {\thmname{#1}\thmnumber{ #2}\thmnote{ (#3)}} % Theorem head spec (can be left empty, meaning 'normal')

\theoremstyle{mytheoremstyle}
\newtheorem{thy}{Theorem}[chapter]   
\newtheorem{coly}{Corollary}[chapter] 
\newtheorem{lem}{Lemma}[chapter] 
\newtheorem{pro}{Proposition}[chapter] 
\newtheorem{Res}{Result}[chapter] 
\newtheorem{prop}{Property}[chapter] 
\newtheorem{remark}{Remark}[chapter] 
\newtheorem{note}{Note}[chapter]

\numberwithin{equation}{chapter}


\DeclarePairedDelimiterX{\innp}[2]{\langle}{\rangle}{#1, #2}              %\innp[\bigg]{x}{y}
\DeclarePairedDelimiterX\norm[1]\lVert\rVert{\ifblank{#1}{\:\cdot\:}{#1}} %\norm[\bigg]{x}

\begin{document}

\chapter{First Chapter}\label{ch1:1}
\section{First Section}\label{ch1:sec1}

This is the first section

\section{Second Section}\label{ch1:sec2}

This is the second section

\subsection{Sub Section}\label{ch1:ssec2}

\begin{itemize}
   \item $\innp{S-\mathbf{d}}{\mathbf{d}}_\mathbf{w} = 0$ i.e. $S-\mathbf{d}$ is orthogonal to $\mathbf{d}$, so we obtain 
            \[
                    S^T\mathbf{d}=(S^T+\mathbf{d}^T-\mathbf{d}^T) \mathbf{d}= \norm[\big]{\mathbf{d}}^2
            \]
\end{itemize}



\end{document}
```